# Teradata: How to remove character \x00 & \x02 from data

Tags: teradata

I am loading data from a teradata database like:

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:teradata://url_of_teradata_db/MAYBENULL=ON,TYPE=FASTEXPORT,charset=ASCII").option("dbtable", "({}) as subq".format(req)).option("driver", "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver").option("user", my_user).option("password", my_password).load()
```

In my data, I get unwanted character like: \x00 & \x02 ...

How can I correctly read those characters **into my spark.read.format*?

I found the **NULLBYTEPREFIX** but I am not sure how to use it

**EDIT :**

my query query is really simple:

```
SELECT MY_ROW FROM MY_TABLE
```

I ask teradata more information about this column and I get:

```
| Column Name     | Type | Nullable | Format | Max length | 
| My_TABLE.MY_ROW | CV   | N        | X(100) | 100        |
```

Comment: Are those characters present in the data within the Teradata database? What is the data type of the corresponding expression in the request (or column in the table)?

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the characters are present within teradata db. You can found the type above :)

Comment: I suppose you could consider using OTRANSLATE function in your query to remove those characters.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check character set of database columns and add those character set into your above query.

You can refer this [link](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Database-SQL-Data-Types-and-Literals/June-2017/Character-and-CLOB-Data-Types/CHARACTER-Data-Type), if you unable to understand the character set in teradata.